# Enter passphrase for key 'travis.pem'

Tags: amazon-ec2, putty

What should be entered as passphrase when loging into EC2 ?

```
stein$ ssh -i "travis.pem" ec2-user@ec2-54-208-53-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

> Enter passphrase for key 'travis.pem':

Comment: how did you generate the key ? did you download straight for aws ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.